# How to send hotkey to nested tmux session

Tags: tmux

I have a tmux config like this on my local and remote machine.

```
is_vim='echo "#{pane_current_command}" | grep -iqE "(^|\/)g?(view|n?vim?)(diff)?$"'

bind-key -n C-h if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-h" "select-pane -L"
```

I'm trying to move to the other pane in my remote session, but it does not get sent to the nested session. How may I send caps lock + h to switch between all of the panes cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you `ssh` from a local pane and then run `tmux` on the remote side.

A simple solution is to add `ssh` to the regex. The downside is `send-keys C-h` will work regardless if there is `tmux` on the remote side. Checking if there is `tmux` on the remote side is not trivial (if possible at all in a robust way).

Additionally you may want `tmux` as well; this will cover tmux sessions nested locally.

Your code modified:

```
is_vim='echo "#{pane_current_command}" | grep -iqE "(^|\/)(g?(view|n?vim?)(diff)?|ssh|tmux)$"'
bind-key -n C-h if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-h" "select-pane -L"
```

Note `select-pane -L` in the inner session is unaware of panes of the outer session. It will only select panes of the inner session. IMO building logic that allows you to move around the panes of the inner session and transparently "jump out" to the outer session when you reach the border would be very hard (again: if possible at all in a robust way).